# SQL Server : LIKE - Finding 1 and not 11 in a string

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a SQL Server table with these values:

```
ID     test
-----------------
1      '1,11,X1'
2      'Q22,11,111,51'
3      '1'
4      '5,Q22,1'
```

If I want to find out which rows contain the comma-separated value '1', I can just do the following and it will work but I'd like to find a better or less wordy way of doing so if it exists. Unfortunately I cannot use RegExp because using `\b1\b` would be awesome here.

```
Select test 
FROM ...
WHERE 
    test LIKE '1,%' 
    OR test = '1' 
    OR test LIKE '%,1' 
    OR test LIKE %,1,%
```

Something like...

```
WHERE 
    test LIKE '%[,{NULL}]1[,{NULL}]%'
```

I know this line isn't correct but you get what I'm after... hopefully ;)

EDITED based on comments below

Comment: can you clarify what your criteria is for selecting rows?  You give example rows but not which ones should be returned.

Comment: also, your query wouldn't work because it would return a row that just had '11' in it

Comment: @Kevin He clearly states that `using \b1\b would be awesome`. That's a `1` preceded by a word boundary and succeded by a word boundary.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos , but that doesn't match his query which he says works.  Hence my request for clarification

Comment: I should be getting back rows 1 3 and 4 because they either equal 1 or ,1 or ,1,

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's true. I think the query is buggy; first predicate should be `'1,%'` instead of `'1%'`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos your correct. I wrote it down wrong. It should be 1,%

Comment: Check out my revised answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use comma-delimited values to store lists.  You should use a junction table.  But, if you have to, the following logic might help:

```
Select test
FROM ...
WHERE ',' + test + ',' like '%,' + '1' + ',%' ;
```

This assumes that what you are looking for is "1" as the entire item in the list.

Note:  You can/should write the `like` pattern as `'%,1,%'`.  I just put it  in three pieces to separate out the pattern you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table 
where ',' + test + ',' like '%,1,%'
```

Comment: His wording isn't clear, but I read it as more than one 1 in a row.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of SplitString functions available if you google around (many here on StackOverflow) that take a comma delimited string like you have, and split it out into multiple rows.  You can CROSS APPLY that table-value function to your query, and then just select for those rows that have '1'.

For example, using this splitstring function here (just one of many):
[T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

You can write this code to get exactly what you want (note, the declare and insert are just to set up test data so you can see it in action):

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (ID int, test varchar(400));
INSERT INTO @test (ID, test)
VALUES(1, '1,11,X1'),
      (2, 'Q22,11,111,51'),
      (3, '1'),
      (4, '5,Q22,1')

SELECT * 
  FROM @test
  CROSS APPLY splitstring(test)
 WHERE [Name] = '1'
```

This query returns this:

```
1  1,11,X1  1
3  1        1
4  5,Q22,1  1
```

Comment: Depending on the splitstring function, you can also use this technique to check if only certain columns are set to '1' as well.  (most return an id / value with the id being the column #)

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
SELECT test 
FROM _tableName_ 
WHERE (test LIKE '1,%' 
       OR test LIKE '%,1' 
       OR test LIKE '%,1,%' 
       OR test LIKE '1')
```

This will return rows that match in order

1. 1 starts a list
2. 1 ends a list
3. 1 is in the middle of a list
4. 1 is its own list

Answer (score 0):

You have to "normalize" your database. If you have multiple attributs for one row, it's a problem!
Add a "One to Many" relation with yours attributs.

You can do like that:

```
ID, test
1, 1
1, 11
1, X1
2, Q22
2, 11
[...]

SELECT test FROM ...
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM ... WHERE test = 1)
```

You primary key is (ID, test) now.

Comment: Not my database but i agree with you!

Comment: Ok... eventually you can create a function that split by comma in a subrequest and doing a `IN` on it.